# Using a JS variable (from an HTML form) throughout a page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, variables, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to take a user input, turn it into a JS variable, and use it in multiple places in the html.

I've included an alert function immediately after the user enters the input and that works, but I can't display the variable at the bottom.

Here's the code:

```
<body>
 <div class="hero-unit">
   <h1> Title </h1>
     <p> This form description </p>  
      <form class="well" name="formInput" action= "#">
       <label>Input</label>
        <input Id="txtvarInput" class="span3" style="margin: 0pt auto;" type="text" placeholder="AAA, BBB, CCC..." data-provide="typeahead" data-items="10" data-source="[&quot;AAA&quot;,&quot;BBB&quot;,&quot;CCC&quot;,&quot;DDD&quot;,&quot;EEE&quot;,&quot;FFF&quot;,&quot;GGG&quot;,&quot;HHH&quot;,&quot;III&quot;,&quot;JJJ&quot;,&quot;KKK&quot;,&quot;LLL&quot;]"/>               
       </label>
      <div class="form-actions" "span3">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn" value="Select" onclick="alert('you chose ' + theInput.value)"/>
         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
          var theInput = document.getElementById('txtvarInput');
         </script>
       </div>
     </form>
   </div>

<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Input:
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      document.write(theInput.value);
    </script>
 </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You should avoid writing the javascript inline with the HTML

Comment: can't you just skip this, and call the element directly? `document.getElementById('txtvarInput').value` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript works a bit differently than you might be imagining.

When you say...

```
document.write(theInput.value);
```

...right in the middle of some html element somewhere, it only calls that once when the page first renders.

If you want to call it when the text input changes or a button is clicked you'll need to put it in a function and call that function when some event happens on some element.

See this link to learn about events: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp

**HOWEVER**, `document.write()` is a bit different where, when called from a function, it will **overwrite the entire page**!

So... in this case you will need to "append" a text element to the `<h1>` element that you are trying to update.

See this link to learn more about the document object model (DOM) and working with its elements: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_element.asp

Once you're familiar with these principals you'll want to make your life a lot easier and your code more cross-browser friendly by checking out a framework for doing these things like jQuery: http://jquery.com/

**UPDATE (ADDED VALUE):**
For those interested, something like what is being asked here can be accomplished quite easily today in "pageless", JavaScript based web applications using AngularJS (http://angularjs.org/). Do read up on the documentation and the appropriate circumstances under which this technology can be utilized. Start with the FAQs (http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) and move into the videos (http://www.youtube.com/user/angularjs).

Comment: -1 for linking to W3Schools (see http://w3fools.com), but +1 for being mostly right.

Comment: @Phrogz I knew that would get me some flack but I use it because it's a bit less scary looking for beginners... this link isn't quite as inviting: http://www.w3.org/DOM/ ;) Do you have a site that might be a better resource for cases like this?

Comment: @ResistDesign [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event); usually googling for any phrase along with "mdn" will land you there.

Answer (score 2):

In a `document.onload` function I would put the following:

```
theInput.onchange = function(event){
  document.getElementById('h1Id').innerHTML = theInput.value
}
```

presumably you want the HTML to update everytime the user changes the input?

Comment: You mean `event.target.value`; but then again if you already have a handle to `theInput` you could just use `theInput.value` since the function is a closure.

Comment: Note that linking only to the `change` event will not work for HTML5 range input; you need a `input` event handler. (Not that the OP is using them, but a warning to others.)

Answer (score 0):

The update should happen after the button is clicked.

```
<html>
<body>
 <div class="hero-unit">
   <h1> Title </h1>
     <p> This form description </p>  
      <form class="well" name="formInput" action= "#">
       <label>Input</label>
        <input Id="txtvarInput" class="span3" style="margin: 0pt auto;" type="text" placeholder="AAA, BBB, CCC..." data-provide="typeahead" data-items="10" data-source="[&quot;AAA&quot;,&quot;BBB&quot;,&quot;CCC&quot;,&quot;DDD&quot;,&quot;EEE&quot;,&quot;FFF&quot;,&quot;GGG&quot;,&quot;HHH&quot;,&quot;III&quot;,&quot;JJJ&quot;,&quot;KKK&quot;,&quot;LLL&quot;]"/>               
       </label>
      <div class="form-actions" "span3">

        // UPDATED HERE
        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn" value="Select" 
          onclick="alert('you chose ' + theInput.value);     
          document.getElementById('inputresult').innerHTML = theInput.value;"/>

         <script language="JavaScript" type="Text/JavaScript">
          var theInput = document.getElementById('txtvarInput');
         </script>
       </div>
     </form>
   </div>

<div class="page-header">
  <h1 id="myh1">Input:</h1>

   <!-- UPDATED HERE -->
    <div id="inputresult">

    </div>
 </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Provide semantic markup, including placeholders for your values, e.g.

   ```html
   Input: <span class="inp-reflector"></span>

   <!-- Or, for HTML5+ -->
   Input: <output class="inp-reflector"></output>
   ```
2. Procedurally attach one or more event handlers to your input:

   ```js
   var inp = document.querySelector('#input-id');
   inp.addEventListener('input',update,false);
   inp.addEventListener('change',update,false);
   ```
3. Have your event handler(s) retrieve the value of the input and change your page:

   ```js
   function update(evt){
     var changedElement = evt.target;
     var newValue = changedElement.value;
     var outputs  = document.querySelectorAll('.inp-reflector');
     outputs.forEach(function(out){
       out.innerHTML = newValue;
     });
   }
   ```

*The answer intentionally uses JavaScript features from modern browsers only.*

---

For a generic reflection system:

```
<input class="reflectable" data-reflect-to=".bar">
…
document.querySelectorAll('.reflectable').forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('change',reflect,false);
  el.addEventListener('input',reflect,false);
});

function reflect(evt){
  var outSelector = evt.getAttribute('data-reflect-to');
  document.querySelectorAll(outSelector).forEach(function(o){
    o.innerHTML = evt.target.value;
  });
}
```

Comment: I might be confused.. but in the case of more than one input and output, where is the link from a specific input to a specific output?

Comment: @Arth The mapping is implicit in which objects you place the event handler on and what elements the handler chooses to update. For a generic system that allows you to specify _n_ inputs each mapping to arbitrary outputs (based on a selector), see my edit.

Answer (score -1):

Inline script such as the following, will execute as soon as the browser renders them.  So the script below executes as soon as the browser is rendering that particular script tag and way before the user has entered any input, therefore the global variable you have created is not populated with any data inputted by the user.  You need to attach an event to the submit button on the page that sets the global variable and displays it on the page.

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Input:
    <script language="JavaScript" type="Text/JavaScript">
      document.write(theInput.value);
    </script>
 </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: If you know enough to recommend against mixing logic with content, how do you recommend inline script elements and `document.write`?

Comment: @Phrogz, I did not recommend using inline script, I just explained to the poster what their script was doing and why it was not working.  If you would read the post carefully you will notice that I say 'Inline script such as the follow,'  and then post the offending script below my statement.  You would also notice after a careful reading that I suggest attaching an event to the submit button, which would separate the concerns.

Comment: Then consider my downvote a reflection of the fact that your answer provides conflicting advice and includes a code sample that is a bad idea (without indicating that it is such) and fails to include a code sample for any best practice. If you edit your answer with code that I believe is appropriate I will change my vote. :)